# How to change html component posstion when switching from Mobile view to Web view

Tags: html, css, bottomnavigationview

I have a small web application where it consist of a navigation bar at the top. I need to make this web application support Mobile web view. Therefor i need to change the position of the top navigation bar to the bottom navigation bar when switching from web view to mobile view.  How to achieve this?. can i use SaSS for this?. Here is my react component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import BottomNavigation from "../components/bottomnavigation";
import { GetPosts, LikePost } from "../actions/postActions";


class HomeContainer extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <BottomNavigation/>
    );
  }
}

let mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    posts: state.post.posts
  };
};

let mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    Getposts: data => {
      dispatch(GetPosts());
    },
    Likeposts: data => {
      dispatch(LikePost(data));
    }
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeContainer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you are using for your frontend dev. When I do web applications I love to use bootstrap. It gives me a bunch of css classes out of the box that help me create a responsive frontend that will do what I need it to on any screen size. Long story short, I would use media queries, the bootstrap layout grid, or a combination of both.

There are many tutorials on youtube. This guy shows how the basics work for the bootstrap layout grid. https://youtu.be/GDwWmrpCa30

Media queries are useful when you need your UI to do something different based on the current device screen size. This can be used without the need for bootstrap, but can also be used with bootstrap to make really responsive apps.  There are also countless tutorials on youtube for that also, but here is a good one to check out. https://youtu.be/2KL-z9A56SQ

Let me know if I can be of further assistance. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Try to edit the BottomNavigation. Change its className to a responsive class and use @media

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

.bottomNavigation{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
}

}
```